# MySQL Order by total, not partial sum for a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have dataset that contains users ('reply_email'), categories in which they can reply and then their reply count. I have written a query that orders the users and categories by the reply count:

```
SELECT
    advert_reply.advert_reply_email,
    advert.advert_category_fk_categoryid,
    COUNT(advert_reply_id)
FROM volnamista_daily.advert_reply
JOIN advert ON advert.advert_id = advert_reply.advert_fk_advertid
WHERE advert_reply_created > '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY advert_reply_email, advert.advert_category_fk_categoryid
ORDER BY COUNT(advert_reply_id) DESC, advert.advert_category_fk_categoryid;
```

Now the data are ordered by partial sum for both users and categories.

But I would like to order the data in the following way: I would like to see first the user with most replies in total and all the categories for him even though there is only one reply for the category. Then the second user by total count and all the categories for him etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is a "user"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff user is reply_email in the data

Answer (score 0):

You can user window functions.  Assuming that `advert_reply.advert_reply_email` is the "user":

```
ORDER BY MAX(COUNT(advert_reply_id)) OVER (PARTITION BY advert_reply.advert_reply_email) DESC, 
         advert_reply.advert_reply_email,
         advert.advert_category_fk_categoryid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8dca47b0e3f64f928965b4888596d7dd) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, but there is a syntax error an I cannot spot it. Or do I need to adjust the first part of the statement somehow as well?

Comment: @Pawels . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  The code works fine.

Comment: I see it is working correctly there. But when I copy the whole query to my editor, it doesn't validate the syntax, stating problem: "OVER" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'

Comment: @Pawels . . . This does require MySQL version 8+.

Comment: I see. If I checked correctly, my version is 5.7.23.

Comment: @Pawels . . . This is much trickier in older versions of MySQL.  You might want to consider upgrading.  The more recent versions of MySQL are much more powerful.

Comment: Thank you for the advise but this is simply the version of our corporate db.